# Converse of Dirichlet test: a result about existence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am wondering whether the following converse to the Dirichlet's test of convergence is true.

> Let $\lambda_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k$ is **unbounded** as $n \to \infty$. Then there exists a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $\sum \lambda_n x_n$ diverges.

There is a delicate balance between $\lambda$ and $x$, which makes it really hard to prove the above result or find a counterexample.

**Is the statement above true?**

In fact, if a counterexample exists, then there might be some possibilities of strengthening the Dirichlet test to a stronger result.

Comment: Sorry for my incorrect answer. I think one can assume that $\lambda_k\to0$ (if not,  $x_n:=\frac{1}{n\lambda_n}$ -or  define this way for a subsequence where $\lambda_n$ is away from zero- may works), Just a giess

Answer (score 2):

**First step** : Let's begin with the case where $\lambda_k \in \mathbb{R}_+$ for all $k$. In that case, the sequence $(S_n)_{n \geq 1}$ defined for all $n \geq 1$ by $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k$$ is increasing and diverges to $+\infty$. Considering $$x_n = \frac{1}{S_n}$$

You have for all $N, p \in \mathbb{N}^*$,
$$\sum_{k=N}^{N+p} \lambda_k x_k = \sum_{k=N}^{N+p} \frac{\lambda_k}{S_k} \geq \sum_{k=N}^{N+p} \frac{\lambda_k}{S_{N+p}} = \frac{S_{N+p}-S_N}{S_{N+p}} = 1 - \frac{S_N}{S_{N+p}}$$

which tends to $1$ as $p$ tends to $+\infty$, so you see that the sequence $\sum \lambda_k x_k$ is not Cauchy, so it does not converge.

**Second step :** Now we come back to the general case, where $\lambda_k \in \mathbb{C}$. We can suppose without loss of generality that for every $k \geq 1$, one has $\lambda_k \neq 0$ (just removing the zero terms from the sums).

First, notice that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n |\lambda_k| \geq \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k \right|$$

so because $\sum \lambda_k$ is supposed to be unbounded, then $\sum |\lambda_k|$ diverges to $+\infty$. By the first case applied to $|\lambda_k|$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ which tends to $0$, such that $\sum |\lambda_k|x_k$ diverges. Define $(y_n)$ by
$$y_n = \frac{\overline{\lambda_n}}{|\lambda_n|}x_n$$

Of course $|y_n|=|x_n|$ so $(y_n)$ tends to $0$, and $$\sum \lambda_k y_k = \sum \lambda_k \frac{\overline{\lambda_k}}{|\lambda_k|}x_k = \sum |\lambda_k|x_k$$

which diverges by definition of the sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: Thank you. But what about the case with different signs? (That's kind of the point of the Dirichlet test :)

Comment: @MaJoad I gave you the positive case as a hint, since the general case can easily be deduced from it. See my edit.