# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum \frac{-a_n}{\log a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume that $0<a_n<1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ is a sequence in $c_0\setminus\ell^1$, that is, such that $\sum a_n$ is divergent but $a_n\to0$.

What can be said about the convergence/divergence of $\displaystyle \sum \frac{-a_n}{\log a_n}$?

---

If one thinks on $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ (probably the classical example of sequence in $c_0\setminus\ell^1$), then $\frac{-a_n}{\log a_n}=\frac{1}{n\log n}$ wich os also divergent.

My intuition says that the answer yo my question is DIVERGENT for all such sequences $(a_n)_n$, but I cannot find a way to prove/disprove this conjecture.

If this were true, I think I can give a complete answer to [this question about the Dirichlet Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930668/converse-of-dirichlet-test-a-result-about-existence).

Comment: $a_n = \frac1{n log(n)}$ ?

Comment: How can handle with $\sum \frac{1}{n(\log n)(\log(n\log n))}$ ?

Comment: The general term is equivalent to \$frac1{n (log n)^2}$ which is convergent

Comment: If you put as answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $a_n = \frac1{nlogn}$ we get $- \frac{a_n}{log(a_n)} \sim \frac1{n (logn)^2}$ wich is the general term of a convergent serie.